# I have collected data for cbse registration through Google form

Tags: python

I have collected data for cbse registration through Google form.I have also taken students photos using google form. I am trying to download the image of the students from Google Sheet. I have kept the students photos in Google Sheet One colum and Name of the students in next column. I have copy and paste the two column data in office excel 2019.

Now I have written a python code to download the photo of the students from that excel file. My code is as below :

```py
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

import  urllib.request

from openpyxl import load_workbook
print('Checking Download Status of the Images file......')

wb=load_workbook("Students Details.xlsx")
sheet1=wb["Sheet1"]
mkro=sheet1.max_row

for i in range(1,mkro):
    download_status=sheet1.cell(row=i+1,column=3).value

    url=(sheet1.cell(row=i+1,column=1).value)
    savefileas='D:/Examination/CBSE/Registration/2021-22/Std.XI/Students `enter code here`Photos/Temp - Photographs/'+(sheet1.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value)+'.jpg'
        
    if download_status==None:
        
        a=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        print(a.getcode())
        
        if a.getcode() == 200:
            print('Connecting Server to download the image')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,savefileas )
            print('Photograph of '+str(i)+' - '+sheet1.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value+' downloaded successfully')
            sheet1.cell(row=i+1,column=3).value='downloaded successfully'
            wb.save("Students Details.xlsx")
           
        elif a.getcode() != 200:
            print('Unable to download now')
            sys.exit()
    elif download_status=='downloaded successfully':
        print(str(i)+'-> '+sheet1.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value+' Already downloaded')
```

Comment: But it gives the following error : after 50download :

Comment: please, add the error message to the question by editing it.